# Count number of occurrence, with order of string counted only 1x

Tags: r, match

*Revised question with more accurate dataset example*

I have several different lists, with each lists containing many characters. I've written up a very short example here

```
List1 <- "A + B + C + D + E:F + F:E"

List2<- "A + B + C + E:F + F:E + G:H + H:G"

List3 <- "J + K + L + L:H + L:H1"
```

I'm trying to find the frequency of occurrence through all of these lists but the duplicate of some items is causing problems.

Through a lot of loops, and X %in% Y, strsplit (splitting before and after ":"), I've gotten this

```
 sig_var8
     var count
 1     0     0
 2     A     2
 3     B     2
 4     C     2
 5     D     1
 6   E:F     2
 7   F:E     2
 8   G:H     1
 9   H:G     1
 10    J     1
 11    K     1
 12    L     1
 13  L:H     1
 14 L:H1     1
```

What I would like is this:

```
sig_var8
     var count
 1     0     0
 2     A     2
 3     B     2
 4     C     2
 5     D     1
 6   E:F     2
 7   G:H     1
 8     J     1
 9     K     1
 10    L     1
 11  L:H     1
 12 L:H1     1
```

Note: in list 1, E:F and F:E is considered the same and only appears once. Same with list 2 where G:H == H:G, and only counted once. Note that grep isn't the best because L:H and L:H1 in list 3 are not the same, they need to be counted separately (hence the %in%).

Here's the code that I've worked on:

```
sig_var8<-data.frame(matrix(data=0,nrow=1,ncol=2))
colnames(sig_var8)<-c("var","count")
sig_var8[,1]<-as.character(sig_var8[,1])
sig_var8[,2]<-as.numeric(sig_var8[,2])


for(list in 1:3){
  temp_list<-get(paste0("List",list)) #get the equation above
  assign(paste0("List",list,"a"), gsub(" ","",temp_list)) #remove all spaces in the sentence
  assign(paste0("List",list,"a_split"), strsplit(get(paste0("List",list,"a")),"[+]")) #split where "+" are
  temp_listA<-get(paste0("List",list,"a_split"))[[1]]
  for (item in 1:length(temp_listA)){
    if(isTRUE(temp_listA[item] %in% sig_var8[,1])){
      row_n<-which(sig_var8[,1]==temp_listA[item])
      sig_var8[row_n,2]<-sig_var8[row_n,2]+1
     }
     if(isFALSE(temp_listA[item] %in% sig_var8[,1])){
       row_n<-nrow(sig_var8)
       sig_var8[row_n+1,1]<-temp_listA[item]
       sig_var8[row_n+1,2]<-1
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Does the output of `table(c(List1, List2, List3))` take you closer to what you want?

Comment: No, I tried that and I just see the unique values of each list, whereas I want the count of each object in each list across all lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Rui's answer I think this will do what you want

```r
List1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E:F","F:E")
List2<- c("A","B","C","E:F","F:E","G:H","H:G")
List3 <- c("J","K","L","L:H","L:H1")

# make list of all objects starting with List
Lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^List"))

# function to split, sort, and stitch the duplicates
split.sort <- function(x) {
  ifelse(length(x) > 1, paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":"), x)
}

# apply function to each of the Lst lists and remove duplicates
Lst <- lapply(Lst, function(y) unique(sapply(strsplit(y, ":"), split.sort)))

# get frequency
table(unlist(Lst))
#> 
#>    A    B    C    D  E:F  G:H  H:L H1:L    J    K    L 
#>    2    2    2    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like the following does what you want.

```
Lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^List"))

Lst <- lapply(Lst, function(x) {
  L <- strsplit(x, ":")
  res <- sapply(L, function(y){
    paste(sort(y), collapse = ":")
  })
  unique(res)
})

table(unlist(Lst))
#
#   A    B    C    D  E:F  G:H  H:L H1:L    J    K    L 
#   2    2    2    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback! @Rui, it's not quite what I want because E:F is = 4 vs 2. In list 1, E:F should only be counted once (because E:F and F:E are the same here) and counted 1x in List 2. So E:F should be =2. Same idea with G:H, G:H and H:G are the same, so G:H = 1

Comment: yes this method gives me the result I want! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this is what you are looking for, but if it is I will annotate it.

```
List1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E:F","F:E")
List2<- c("A","B","C","E:F","F:E","G:H","H:G")
List3 <- c("J","K","L","L:H","L:H1")

Lst <- list(List1, List2, List3)

keep_me <- lapply(Lst, function(x) !duplicated(lapply(strsplit(x, ":", fixed = T), sort)))
Lst_cleaned <- unlist(Map(`[`, Lst, keep_me))
table(Lst_cleaned)
Lst_cleaned
   A    B    C    D  E:F  G:H    J    K    L  L:H L:H1 
   2    2    2    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Edit: added explanation below. Let me know if anything is still unclear or if you run into more issues. I use `List1` for the beginning to demonstrate what `lapply` is doing for each list element. Also, as a side-note, breaking it down made me realize you do not need to use `which` if you do not want to. You can use the logical vector in `Map` to subset the elements of `Lst`

```
# Spliting the string on the colon and sorting the elements
lapply(strsplit(List1, ":", fixed = T), sort)
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] "C"

[[4]]
[1] "D"

[[5]]
[1] "E" "F"

[[6]]
[1] "E" "F"

# Logical vector for the elements are NOT duplicated
!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(List1, ":", fixed = T), sort))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# Which gives the indices for TRUE's
which(!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(List1, ":", fixed = T), sort)))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

# Now, all together: lapply is applying the above logic to 
# each elemnt in Lst, it returns a list of the indices that are not
# duplicates for each vector
lapply(Lst, function(x) which(!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(x, ":", fixed = T), sort))))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 6

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

keep_me <- lapply(Lst, function(x) which(!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(x, ":", fixed = T), sort))))

# Map subsets (`[`) Lst by the indices in keep_me, and unlist  
# flattens the list (i.e., unlist makes it a vector)
Map(`[`, Lst, keep_me)
[[1]]
[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "E:F"

[[2]]
[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "E:F" "G:H"

[[3]]
[1] "J"    "K"    "L"    "L:H"  "L:H1"

unlist(Map(`[`, Lst, keep_me))
 [1] "A"    "B"    "C"    "D"    "E:F"  "A"    "B"    "C"    "E:F"  "G:H"  "J"    "K"    "L"    "L:H"  "L:H1"
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Thanks! That's exactly the end result of what I'm looking for. I put a better example of my code above and a better explanation of what I'm looking for. I don't quite understand your code well enough to understand whether this would work with my data structure though?

Comment: @Tammy, I just updated it with an explanation. Let me know if you run into issues!!

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation is phenomenal and the code is MUCH more elegant than what I wrote. I do have a few questions though. 1. When you say, using 'which' is unnecessary, do you mean when you used it in defining keep_me? 2. I'm not quite sure I understand what you did with map and '['. Did you tell it to basically combine the lists, i.e. Lst[[1]], Lst[[2]],Lst[[3]] by asking it to look for the character "[" in Lst?

Comment: 1. Correct! 2. The `[` is just subsetting each element of the list. You can swap out `[` for `subset` if that is clearer to understand.  So, in this case, for every element of the list `Lst` it subsets the corresponding element of `keep_me`. Look at `Lst[[1]]` and 
`keep_me[[1]]`. And then subsetting the first elements of `Lst` by `keep_me` can be done like this: `Lst[[1]][keep_me[[1]]]` or `subset(Lst[[1]], keep_me[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks to both @nsinghs and Andrew -- both gave me different solutions to what I wanted in a very tidy manner. Thanks for the explanations!